# gcc CortexM4 single precision FPU: Why uses eg. 'powf' double precision functions eg '__extendsfdf2' or '__aeabi_ddiv'

Tags: cortex-m

While checking for a STM32F4 Cortex M4 with GCC compiled list file I wonder why many double precision float functions are linked, eg:

> __aeabi_drsub
>   __aeabi_dsub
>   __subdf3
>   __aeabi_dadd
>   __adddf3
>   __floatunsidf
>   __aeabi_ui2d
>   __floatsidf
>   __aeabi_i2d
>   __aeabi_f2d
>   __extendsfdf2
>   __floatundidf
>   __aeabi_ul2d
>   __floatdidf
>   __aeabi_l2d

I'm using flags to avoid any double calculation:
-fsingle-precision-constant
-Wdouble-promotion

and I added 'f' behind every constants, eg '2.3f'

Is there any possibility to avoid this?

Comment: You could dump the assembly from the ELF to figure out why those functions are getting called ...

`objdump -d build/nrf52.elf`

and then search for occurrences the list you have. For example, something like:

`00000180 <main>: [...] 194:       f003 fd22       bl      3bdc <__aeabi_dmul>`

would indicate `__aeabi_dmul` is being called from the `main()` function

You'll also want to make sure you are compiling with the `-ffunction-sections` flag and linking with `-Wl,--gc-sections` so any functions which are not called are removed from the final binary.

Comment: investigating the list file and looking after '__aeabi_ddiv' it's beeing called by 'powf' which I'm using from my code with '__builtin_powf'. I assumed 'powf' is for single precision. If I replace 'powf' with 'pow' the float is converted with '__aeabi_f2d' before 'pow' is called. I'm using already your both recommended flags.